# Problem mounting ssfsh with fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, sshfs

So, I'm trying to mount a local network folder through sshfs. The following is in my fstab:

```
jackie@192.168.2.33:/home/jackie/.kodi/ /home/jackie/KBox/ fuse.sshfs delay_connect,_netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,identityfile=/home/jackie/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

Everything works fine when I manually use `$ mount KBox/`, but on boot when trying to access the mount I get the following error:

```
jackie@The-Iron-Throne:~$ ls KBox/
ls: cannot access KBox/: Input/output error
```

Only after the following can I access the mount:

```
jackie@The-Iron-Throne:~$ sudo umount KBox/
jackie@The-Iron-Throne:~$ mount KBox/
jackie@The-Iron-Throne:~$ ls KBox/
addons  media  sounds  system  temp  userdata
```

I assume my fstab entry is correct, otherwise I don't think the `$ mount KBox/` command would work as expected, but for some reason it won't work on boot.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, I am not right. But why you  don't do this in a such way:

```
sshfs  /home/jackie/.kodi/ jackie@192.168.2.33:/home/jackie/KBox
```

and umount this folder:

```
fusermount -u /home/jackie/KBox
```

After the first code line, you can use parameters such in your query.

And in documentation for umount I find this useful information:

```
   Note  that  a  file  system cannot be unmounted when it is ‘busy’ - for
   example, when there are open files on it, or when some process has  its
   working  directory  there,  or  when  a swap file on it is in use.  The
   offending process could even be umount itself - it opens libc, and libc
   in  its  turn may open for example locale files.  A lazy unmount avoids
   this problem.
```

For more detailed information use this link: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/umount.8.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at here. Clearly the un-mounting process isn't a concern (at least I don't think) because it mounts fine after the umount.

And, as far as I understand it, that sshfs command is completely reversed: I'm trying to mount the remote directory .kodi to the local directory KBox.

My problem isn't the un-mounting, it's mounting at boot.